# Bootstrap Form Crashes after Submit clicking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've creating a Bootstrap form and the datas will send over a ajax code part.
The Problem is that the form crashes after I click the submit button..
Here the Code:

```
   <script>


      $( '#frmContact').submit( function() {

       var formControl = true;

      var nachname =$( '#nachname' );


     }
     if(nachname.val() == '')
     {
                    formControl = false;

         $( '#frmGrpNachname' ).addClass( 'has-error' );
         $('#frmGrpNachname').append('<div class="help-block">' + 'error' + '</div>'); 


     }
      if(formControl) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: { keyword:vorname }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            $( '#message' ).addClass( 'alert' );
            $( '#message' ).addClass( 'alert-success' );
            $( '#message').html( msg );
        });
    }

    return false;


 } );
 </script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: why 'crashes'? what the error you receive?

Comment: vorname seems is not defined in this scope

Comment: It is defined some lines before... Sorry.
Here the  full code http://codebin.org/view/54dd9fe1
I Dont know how to post the code here in the comment box..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an aditional `}`

```
...
    var nachname =$( '#nachname' );

   }
   if(nachname.val() == '')
   {
...
```

change it for:

```
...
    var nachname =$( '#nachname' );

   if(nachname.val() == '')
   {
...
```

Comment: To add, hitting F12 in your browser to get the developer tools/console would be helpful too, because then the error being thrown could of been seen

Comment: Thanks but the Console don't show anything. That whole site crashes... Maybe  Maybe teh whole code can show the wrong row... ` I now that i shoudl post the code here but I don't know how... Here the Link: http://codebin.org/view/54dd9fe1 SOrry at the mod..